# HardFault caused probably by strcpy

Tags: c, freertos, lpc

The function below runs in LPC1769. I use FreeRTOS version 10.
I am having `HardFault`. I have debugged and I think I cornered the issue after long hours.

If I run this function it gives `HardFault`. Initially, I suspected `malloc` in `substr3` function causes it. Freeing memory allocations didn't help. I therefore started to comment-out the code block by block until I find more accurate location of the issue in the `parseMessage` function.

If I comment out the lines between `/* START OF PROBLEMATIC AREA   */` and `/* END OF PROBLEMATIC AREA   */`
the rest of code works without a single hiccup.

All I do in that code block, I assign values in the struct variables. The struct is global and initialized. I believe that that lines are causing the issue eventually. Maybe indirectly, I don't know that far.

e.g. `strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucActualID, pid);`

If I run all the codes in the `parseMessage`, it works for one or a few messages, they parsed OK and then MCU stops responding.

Struct in a file called `common.h`

```
struct ProductInfoLeft
{
    char ucActualID[ 7 ];  
    char ucProductName[ 13 ];
    char ucBestBeforeDate[ 13 ];
    char ucPrinted[ 4 ];
    char ucToBePrinted[ 4 ];
    char ucLane[ 3 ];
    char ucLcdNumber [ 2 ];
    char ucPrinterLane [ 3 ];
    char ucSupplierInfo [ 13 ];
};
extern struct ProductInfoLeft productInfoLeft;

struct ProductInfoRight
{
    char ucActualID[ 7 ];
    char ucProductName[ 13 ];
    char ucBestBeforeDate[ 13 ];
    char ucPrinted[ 4 ];
    char ucToBePrinted[ 4 ];
    char ucLane[ 3 ];
    char ucLcdNumber [ 2 ];
    char ucPrinterLane [ 3 ];   
    char ucSupplierInfo [ 13 ];
};
extern struct ProductInfoRight productInfoRight;
```

Struct initialization takes place in a file called `lcdtasks.c`;

```
struct ProductInfoLeft productInfoLeft = { 
    .ucActualID = "",
    .ucProductName = "",
    .ucBestBeforeDate = "",
    .ucPrinted = "",
    .ucToBePrinted = "",
    .ucLane = "",
    .ucLcdNumber = "",
    .ucPrinterLane = "",
    .ucSupplierInfo = ""
};

struct ProductInfoRight productInfoRight = { 
    .ucActualID = "",
    .ucProductName = "",
    .ucBestBeforeDate = "",
    .ucPrinted = "",
    .ucToBePrinted = "",
    .ucLane = "",
    .ucLcdNumber = "",
    .ucPrinterLane = "",
    .ucSupplierInfo = ""
};
```

And the parser function in another file called `uarttask.c`;

```
void parseMessage(char * message){
        //Sample data
        //const char* str = "7E00002A347C31323030302D3132353330387C33302E30372E323032307C31317C33307C33317C31352D31367C31357C317C57656E67657274880D0000";
          
        // Parsing the frame
        char* start;
        char* len;
        char* cmd;
        char* data;
        char* chksum;
        char* end;
        
        stripEOL(message);
        unsigned int messagelen = strlen(message);
        
        start = substr3(message, 0, 2);
        len = substr3(message, 2, 4);
        cmd = substr3(message, 6, 2); 
        data = substr3(message, 8, messagelen-8-4);
        chksum = substr3(message, messagelen-4, 2);
        end = substr3(message, messagelen-2, 2); 
       
         // Converting hex (only for data) to string
        char str[250];
        hex_to_string(data, str, sizeof(str));
    
        // Parsing the data in variables
        //Sample data content to be parsed in variables;
        //char str1[50] ="7|10000-145310|12.10.2018|1|10|0|15-16|15|1|Wegert";
        char pid[6], pname[12], bbdate[10], pnr[2], ltoprinted[3], lprinted[3], planes[5], laneNr[2], lcdNr[1], sinfo[12];
    
        strcpy(pid, strtok(str , "|"));
        strcpy(pname, strtok(NULL , "|"));
        strcpy(bbdate, strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(pnr , strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(ltoprinted , strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(lprinted, strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(planes, strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(laneNr, strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(lcdNr, strtok(NULL, "|"));
        strcpy(sinfo, strtok(NULL, "|"));
     
        uint8_t resultLCDNr1 = strncmp(lcdNr, "1", 1);
        uint8_t resultLCDNr2 = strncmp(lcdNr, "2", 1); 
        
        uint8_t result7E = strcmp(start, pcStart);
        uint8_t result0D = strcmp(end, pcEnd);   
        uint8_t result2A = strcmp(cmd, pcProductChange);
        uint8_t result30 = strcmp(cmd, pcSupplierChange);
      
        char planeleft[2], planeright[2], tempplanes[5];
        strcpy(tempplanes, planes); // If this is used, the next strcpy causes lprinted variable's first element to be "0\"
        strcpy(planeleft, strtok(tempplanes , "-"));
        strcpy(planeright, strtok(NULL , "-"));  
     
/* START OF PROBLEMATIC AREA   */  
        if (result7E == 0 && result0D == 0){
            if (result2A == 0){ //Product Change
                if (resultLCDNr1 == 0){
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucActualID, pid);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucPrinterLane, planeleft);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucProductName, pname);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucBestBeforeDate, bbdate);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucPrinted, lprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucToBePrinted, ltoprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucLane, laneNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucLcdNumber, lcdNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucSupplierInfo, sinfo);
                }else if (resultLCDNr2 == 0){
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucActualID, pid);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucPrinterLane, planeright);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucProductName, pname);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucBestBeforeDate, bbdate);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucPrinted, lprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucToBePrinted, ltoprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucLane, laneNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucLcdNumber, lcdNr); 
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucSupplierInfo, sinfo);
                }else{
                    return;
                }
                
                SetProductChangeOnLCD(lcdNr);
            }
            if (result30 == 0){ //Supply Change
                if (resultLCDNr1 == 0){
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucActualID, pid);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucPrinterLane, planeleft);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucProductName, pname);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucBestBeforeDate, bbdate);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucPrinted, lprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucToBePrinted, ltoprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucLane, laneNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucLcdNumber, lcdNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoLeft.ucSupplierInfo, sinfo);
                }else if (resultLCDNr2 == 0){
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucActualID, pid);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucPrinterLane, planeright);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucProductName, pname);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucBestBeforeDate, bbdate);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucPrinted, lprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucToBePrinted, ltoprinted);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucLane, laneNr);
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucLcdNumber, lcdNr); 
                    strcpy(productInfoRight.ucSupplierInfo, sinfo);
                }else{
                    return;
                }
                SetSupplierChangeOnLCD(lcdNr);
            }        
        }
/* END OF PROBLEMATIC AREA   */ 
       
     free(start);
     free(len); 
     free(cmd); 
     free(data);
     free(chksum); 
     free(end); 
    }
```

Substring function:

```
char *substr3(char const *input, size_t start, size_t len) { 
    char *ret = malloc(len+1);
    memcpy(ret, input+start, len);
    ret[len]  = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: And what does the data looks like? NTW: show us the substr() function, too please.

Comment: @wildplasser, I added the function as well.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the `strcpy` one at a time to see if one particular one is causing the issue?

Comment: Consider guarding against buffer overflows for each `strcpy` call. The `strcpy` API does not prevent overwriting past the end of the buffer. One option is to use `strncpy` but be careful even with that as it can result in non NUL terminated buffers if not used correctly. If you don't want to change the `strcpy` calls at least add debugging code to check whether the source lengths ever exceed the buffer sizes.

Comment: I liked to stick to the strcpy for the time being, but at least, I can give it a try if it makes a difference. And I will check if there is any buffer overflows by using `sizeof(variable)`

Comment: Not `sizeof`. You need to use `strlen`. And would strongly advise against keeping the current code as is. It's full of buffer overflow exploit vulnerabilities. Feeding in unexpected inputs will blow holes all through the memory.

Comment: @user3121023, it was old version of the data content. May bad, sorry for the confusion. I've updated the content. It is supposed to be like that: `char str1[50] ="7|10000-145310|12.10.2018|1|10|0|15-16|15";`

Comment: @kaylum, I totally agree with you. However, the code is what I have in my current knowledge. All suggestions are greatly welcomed in order to patch the vulnerabilities.

Comment: @user3121023, because, I have to keep one more space for `\0`?

Comment: @user3121023, it was a good catch, thank you. I was actually aware of that extra space for `\0`. But, I've increased length of some figures earlier and I didn't update the array sizes and they didn't fit any more. Now, it works a bit better. It was crashing after a few messages parsed before, now almost after 10-12 messages. if this is my major issue then I am going to debug lengths of every variables using `strlen` for each messages until I find the something doesn't fit and causes a crash. I still like to hear your opinions though

Comment: @user3121023, indeed, there are more. But, it is just wrong sample.This is the correct one; `char str1[50] ="7|10000-145310|12.10.2018|1|10|0|15-16|15|1|Wegert";`

Comment: @Sener In your sample string the 2nd token `10000-145310` has 12 characters. Counting the nul terminator `strcpy(pname, strtok(NULL , "|"));` will overrun the allocated `char pname[12];`.

Comment: @user3121023, yes, right, couple minutes ago I've already figured it out this as I was checking things as per your suggestions around this array lengths.

Comment: @dxiv, yes, you are also right and I've also figured it out minutes ago.
This is the latest correction of the arrays; `char pid[6], pname[13], bbdate[11], pnr[3], ltoprinted[4], lprinted[4], planes[6], laneNr[3], lcdNr[2], sinfo[13];`

Comment: No, I don't allow them to be empty, I put something as default if there is not one. I am still debugging and trying to find the reason why it still hangs after some data reception within that function.

Comment: Check for errors. Check each `strtok` return value for `NULL`. Please create an [MCVE]. Out of curiosity, can you use `scanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, I like to share my findings and resolution of the problems.

There were two issues. One was array sizes with char used for strcpy. There were not properly set as some contributors mentioned.

Once that array sizes fixed, another issue was revealed itself in a clearer manner. It was about the malloc. For some reason although some remarks say otherwise in various resources, if you use malloc within FreeRTOS implementation, there is a chance you might have HardFault. Once I switched to FreeRTOS suggested malloc and free functions, things flattened. HardFault issue magically disappeared.

I've just placed that two wrapper functions (somewhere in a common file) without even changing my malloc and free calls.;

Creating a malloc/free functions that work with the built-in FreeRTOS heap is quite simple. We just wrap the pvPortMalloc/pvPortFree calls:

```
void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = NULL;

    if(size > 0)
    {
        // We simply wrap the FreeRTOS call into a standard form
        ptr = pvPortMalloc(size);
    } // else NULL if there was an error

    return ptr;
}
void free(void* ptr)
{
    if(ptr)
    {
        // We simply wrap the FreeRTOS call into a standard form
        vPortFree(ptr);
    }
}
```

Note that: You can't use that with heap schema #1 but with the others (2, 3, 4 and 5). I would recommend start using portable/MemMang/heap_4.c