# String parsing failes when using a function doing substring in C

Tags: c, freertos

I am having an issue with parsing a string in C. It causes a `HardFault` eventually.

MCU: LPC1769,
OS: FreeRTOS 10,
Toolchain: IAR

In order to test, If I keep sending the same data frame (you may see the sample below in `message` variable in `parseMessage` function),
after 5-6 times parsing it goes OK, parsing works as I expected, and then suddenly falls in `HardFault` when I send one more the exact same string to the function.

I tested the function in [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BJOstXwBP/). I haven't observed any issue.

I have couple of slightly different version of that function below although the result is the same;

```
char *substr3(char const *input, size_t start, size_t len) { 
    char *ret = malloc(len+1);
    memcpy(ret, input+start, len);
    ret[len]  = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

I've extracted the function piece for a better overveiw:
(don't pay attention to `stripEOL(message);` call, it just strips out end-of-line characters, but you can see it in the gdbonline share of mine)

```
void parseMessage(char * message){
        //char* message= "7E00002A347C31323030302D3132353330387C33302E30372E323032307C31317C33307C33317C31352D31367C31357C317C57656E67657274880D";
          
        // Parsing the frame
        char* start;
        char* len;
        char* cmd;
        char* data;
        char* chksum;
        char* end;
        
        stripEOL(message);
        unsigned int messagelen = strlen(message);
        
        start = substr3(message, 0, 2);
        len = substr3(message, 2, 4);
        cmd = substr3(message, 6, 2); 
        data = substr3(message, 8, messagelen-8-4);
        chksum = substr3(message, messagelen-4, 2);
        end = substr3(message, messagelen-2, 2); 
}
```

Only the `data` variable differs in length.

e.g. data --> "347C31323030302D3132353330387C33302E30372E323032307C31317C33307C33317C31352D31367C31357C317C57656E67657274"

A HardFault debug log:

[image]

LR = 0x8667 in disassembly

[image]

PC = 0x2dd0 in disassembly

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984145/hardfault-caused-probably-by-strcpy . Please post an [MCVE] . You do not check `malloc` return value..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think it will write beyond the bounds of `ret` unless the allocation fails (`ret == NULL`) because `start` won't affect offset for `ret`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, no it is not duplicate. it is also mine but, this is more a follow-up.

Comment: @Sener You should check if `malloc` is successful.

Comment: Is there somewhere (not shown) where you free the memory you have `malloc` ed?

Comment: @DavidHoadley, yes, I do free the memory used by the malloc. Please see the onlinegdb link.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Range for input also looks OK for me for the usage from `parseMessage`, provided that the length of passed `message` is long enough.

Comment: @MikeCAT, do you mean something like that `if (ret == NULL)` ?

Comment: @Sener Yes, add that with proper error handling between `malloc` and `memcpy` so that lines to write to buffers pointed by `ret` won't be executed when `ret` is `NULL`.

Comment: Apart from checking the `malloc` return value, the code you provide looks good, so shouldn't fail. As a last resort, I would try providing `message` on the stack, rather than in read-only memory (ie. fill a local array), in case `strcpy` is broken. Failing that, comment stuff out till it works, or run under a proper debugger.

Comment: @MikeCAT, for error handling, using `exit(1);` is advisable? or what would be an effective way of handling this NULL?

Comment: Could it be that `messagelen` is less than 12 in some cases? That would for sure cause problems

Comment: @4386427, no, `messagelen` can not be less than 12 but minimum 13. However, in my test, I am constantly using the same string I mentioned in my post in order to eliminate other possibilities for the time being.

Comment: @MikeCAT, you were right about it. Malloc fails. I simply tried `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or  `exit(-1);`. It stuck in `__exit` as I could observe in disassembly. I've also tried to return an expected string (I manually extracted from the `message` body and `ret "347C..."` ). It didn't help either.Apparently, if I can get over this malloc failure, I will be done with this.

Comment: @MikeCAT, even if I did some error handling and `HardFault` doesn't occur, I have now some weird behavior. Once the malloc failes and I catch it and allow rest of the application continue, next call for `parseMessage`, `substr3` returns same character for all variables which is that `'ð' (0xF0)`.

Comment: However, the ultimate question is why I do have fail in malloc occasionally even though I am constantly using same string to test? How to find the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate to the contributors which they led me to find the solution for my instance.

Since there wasn't a total solution by the contributors and I found a working solution, I'd better be writing for whom may interest in future.

Since I am developing my application on top of FreeRTOS 10 and using malloc from the C library, apparently it wasn't cooping at least with my implementations. It's been said in some resources, you can use standard malloc within FreeRTOS, I couldn't manage myself for some unknown reason. It might have been a help, if I had increased the heap memory, I don't know but I didn't have intention on that as well.

I've just placed that two wrapper functions (somewhere in a common file) without even changing my malloc and free calls.;

Creating a malloc/free functions that work with the built-in FreeRTOS heap is quite simple. We just wrap the pvPortMalloc/pvPortFree calls:

```
void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = NULL;

    if(size > 0)
    {
        // We simply wrap the FreeRTOS call into a standard form
        ptr = pvPortMalloc(size);
    } // else NULL if there was an error

    return ptr;
}
void free(void* ptr)
{
    if(ptr)
    {
        // We simply wrap the FreeRTOS call into a standard form
        vPortFree(ptr);
    }
}
```

**Note that:** You can't use that with heap schema #1 but with the others (2, 3, 4 and 5).
I would recommend start using portable/MemMang/heap_4.c